# Grouping sentences separated by specific word

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to group 2 sub-sentences of whatever reasonable length separated by a specific word (in the example "AND"), where the second can be optional.
Some example:

CASE1:

```
foo sentence A AND foo sentence B
```

shall give

```
"foo sentence A" --> matching group 1

"AND" --> matching  group 2 (optionally)

"foo sentence B" --> matching  group 3
```

CASE2:

```
foo sentence A
```

shall give

```
"foo sentence A" --> matching  group 1
"" --> matching  group 2 (optionally)
"" --> matching  group 3
```

I tried the following regex

```
(.*) (AND (.*))?$
```

and it works but only if, in CASE2, i put an empty space at the final position of the string, otherwise the pattern doesn't match.
If I include the space before "AND" inside round brackets group, in the case 1 the matcher includes the whole string in the first group.
I wondered aroung lookahead and lookbehind assertions, but not sure they can help me.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this regex:

```
^(.*?)(?: (AND) (.*))?$
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:^(.*?)(?: (AND) (.*))?$)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      AND                      'AND'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just using

```
String split[] = sentence.split("AND");
```

That will split the sentence up by your word and give you a list of subparts.

Comment: This is a way but the result shall not be stored in an array. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the results stored in an array?  Because using split returns an array.

Comment: Exactly. Right now I'm managing with groups stored in the matcher.

Comment: Would you explain how this would handle a string like `SANDWICHES ARE TASTY AND I LIKE KITTENS`

Comment: It would split it into two subparts. split[0] == "SANDWICHES ARE TASTY " and split[1] == " I LIKE KITTENS". The .split method also takes regular expressions so you can make it include the whitespace or different cases.  I just wanted to make the example very clear.

Answer (score 2):

## Description

This regex will return the requested string parts into the requested groups. The `and` is optional, if it's not found in the string then the entire string is placed into group 1. All the `\s*?` forces the captured groups to have their white space trimmed automatically.

`^\s*?\b(.*?)\b\s*?(?:\b(and)\b\s*?\b(.*?)\b\s*?)?$`

[image]

## Groups

0 gets the entire matching string

1. gets the string before the seperating word `and`, if no `and` then the entire string appears here
2. gets the separating word, in this case it's `and`
3. gets the second part of the string

## Java Code Example:

Case 1

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "foo sentence A AND foo sentence B";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^\\s*?\\b(.*?)\\b\\s*?(?:\\b(and)\\b\\s*?\\b(.*?)\\b\\s*?)?$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
    if(m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
    }
  }
}

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => foo sentence A AND foo sentence B
    [1] => foo sentence A
    [2] => AND
    [3] =>  foo sentence B
)
```

Case 2, using the same regex

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
class Module1{
  public static void main(String[] asd){
  String sourcestring = "foo sentence A";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("^\\s*?\\b(.*?)\\b\\s*?(?:\\b(and)\\b\\s*?\\b(.*?)\\b\\s*?)?$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(sourcestring);
    if(m.find()){
      for( int groupIdx = 0; groupIdx < m.groupCount()+1; groupIdx++ ){
        System.out.println( "[" + groupIdx + "] = " + m.group(groupIdx));
      }
    }
  }
}

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => foo sentence A
    [1] => foo sentence A
)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I see you used (?: .... ) but not clear the meaning. There is any well-written tutorial around about this?

Comment: (?: starts a non capture group, this allows the ? at the end to make the group optional, while at the same time not placing the matching text in to returned group

Comment: I found also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to make the space after he first sentence optional:

```
(.*\\S) ?(AND (.*))?$
```

Or you could use `split()` to consume the `AND` and any surrounding spaces:

```
String sentences = sentence.spli("\\s*AND\\s*");
```

Comment: That question mark should go after the first `*` if you want it to have any effect at all.

Comment: @TimPietzcker oh yeah. But I think the edit is better than another question mark, because the semantic is clearer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your case 2 is a little strange...

but I would do

```
String[] parts = sentence.split("(?<=AND)|(?=AND)"));
```

you check the `parts.length`. if length==1, then it is case2. you just have the sentence in array, you could add empty string as your "group2/3"

if in case1 you have directly `parts`:

```
[foo sentence A , AND,  foo sentence B]
```

Comment: Would you explain how this would handle a string like `SANDWICHES ARE TASTY AND I LIKE KITTENS`